# Installing Chrome on Red hat

Tags: google-chrome, installation, redhat, yum

We  have failed trying to install Chrome version `google-chrome-stable-70.0.3538.77-1.x86_64` on Redhat linux environment version 7.2.

We have created a yum repository and had done `yum install google-chrome-stable` but it fails at a step looking up for liberation-fonts stating requires liberation-fonts.

All the fonts with latest version are installed on it. I am attaching the installation logs and list of fonts installed on server.

I also tried install with `.rpm` link still had the same issue, and just to filter it out installed on different server of same os- still had same error.

[Link to Logs:](https://15104268797498972201.googlegroups.com/attach/486f51a2ac12/chrome_install.txt?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHuTXRb1FzAN27pwcCVyw8GhM2VrY-qSsF2C8RejlYRX4lXsOX7-GOfxpfRr3tVYwWeug_RnSwpPwl5q8w0mEtnsgq4B9xQtByvyAq4RbicI4RCgYE)

[Link to List of fonts:](https://15104268797498972201.googlegroups.com/attach/486f51a2ac12/file_stage.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFj7n8SlcIBqYcYK-ucVcqFBygV7s6AOqigvTeN3LOBx8XFY2OJ98ibNuRwQqM9y7z2MbnoKEoYaK4aDXUetHMecJOATLFuCOJeeQdw2Wj_DhK-upc)

Just to add we had no trouble with version `69.0.3497.92` and Google doesn't allow us to download previous versions of Chrome - at least for Redhat OS.

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth, I resolved this by installing it via rpm a package from a CentOS mirror on my laptop running redhat.  In particular I installed this package: liberation-fonts-1.07.2-16.el7.noarch.rpm.  Being a noarch file concerning fonts I wasn't concerned too much where it came from.  I have doubts even the Chrome really needs this package since my installation had already several packages for liberation-fonts, including libertation-fonts-common but it allowed the chrome package to be installed.

Comment: Could you provide yours workaround commands?